# Pytorch cross entropy (IndexError: Target 2 is out of bounds)

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I am new to pytorch and pyG. I am facing an error.

why I am getting the following error:

```
File "/home/es/anaconda3/envs/pyg-meta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1164, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/home/es/anaconda3/envs/pyg-meta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3014, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
IndexError: Target 2 is out of bounds.
```

This is my code and the shape of

```
(Pdb) out.shape
torch.Size([64, 2])
(Pdb) Yt_train.shape
torch.Size([64])
```

This is for batch size 64 of `pytorch dataloader` in a for loop over.

```
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
for data in loader:
    _, out = model(data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)
    Yt_train = data.y.type(torch.LongTensor)
    loss = criterion(out, Yt_train)
```

How to resolve this issue? what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Yt_train` has the correct shape, but should contain values from {0, 1} -- what pytorch is complaining about is the presence of a value 2, which is outside the range of the tensor `out`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I missed out that the predicted labels should be compared with another array (`train_labels: tensor([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, ....])`, instead of `data.y` in the `loader`. How to send this train_label with the same batch of `loader`. I mean `loss = criterion(out, train_label[same batch of loader from this tensor should be taken])`. How to do this?

Comment: That's a different question, completely unrelated to your original one, and frankly not one I understand.